# How to load views via Ajax with Zend Framework?

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

Is it possible to load views with ajax in the zend framework, that way the layout page doesn't get refreshed, just the main content div?

Answer (score 5):

use Ajax context switching you can do it by adding this to your init function in your controller

```
public function init()
{
 $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
 $ajaxContext->addActionContext('my', 'html') //my is your action
                ->initContext();
}
```

The html parameter is the type of Ajax request. it can also be JSON or XML

```
public function myAction() {
    // get what you are sending to your view : data
    $this->view->data = $data;
}
```

create a view `my.ajax.phtml` to which which myAction will attempt to render to it by default 
and then include my.ajax.phtml in your view (your main content div)

Answer (score 1):

With Zend 1.12 we used the Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Json;

**Controller:**

```
use Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Json;

class MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function init() {
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Json());
    }

    public function fooAction() {
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(200);
        $this->_helper->json(array('value' => 1));
    }
}
```

**View:**

- No view file

**Output:**

```
{"value":1}
```

**Call:**

```
http://example/my/foo
```